# Build "Rock, Paper, Scissors" in JavaScript. Can anyone find the syntaxError?

Tags: javascript, function

I am stock here I cant find the Error. 
This exercise, is the part 2 of the codeacademy for JavaScript. In this exercise, I need to  write out the if / else if / else statement using the conditions you see in my code.

```
var userChoice = ne
var ne = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34); {
    computerChoice = "rock" ;
} else if ( 0.34  <=  computerChoice <= 0.67); {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Comment: if (computerChoice < 0.34); { << there is an extra ;
and  0.34  <=  computerChoice <= 0.67 won't work, you have to split it

Comment: I had an extra ; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `}else if ( 0.34 <= computerChoice && computerChoice <= 0.67) {`, also remove the semicolons between the `)`'s and the `{`'s.

```
var ne = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var userChoice = ne;
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock" ;
} else if ( 0.34 <= computerChoice && computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

semi colon here... `if (computerChoice < 0.34); {`

should read `if (computerChoice < 0.34) {`

... and there is another one in the next `else if`

... and three way comparrison is invalid... `0.34  <=  computerChoice <= 0.67`

try this...

```
var userChoice = ne
var ne = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock" ;
} else if ( 0.34  <=  computerChoice && computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```